# Better way to get the right value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am having some trouble trying to get a value from a json. To start, I have an array of json, each one have a name (atributo), a similarity (forget about this one) and finally an array named valores with keys and values (chave = key / valor = value).

So I have a lot of cases and each case have a value from this array like the example below. What I want is to take the value from the Valores using the key from my case.

Right know I am using two for's, one to find the right atributo and the other to find the right key. Is there any way easier to do this? If is needed, I can remodel this json schema.

My array:

```
[
  {
    "atributo": "date",
    "similaridade": "Sim",
    "valores": [
      {"chave": "Desconhecido", "valor": "?"},
      {"chave": "Abril", "valor": "0"},
      {"chave": "Maio", "valor": "1"},
      {"chave": "Junho", "valor": "2"},
      {"chave": "Julho", "valor": "3"},
      {"chave": "Agosto", "valor": "4"},
      {"chave": "Setembro", "valor": "5"},
      {"chave": "Outubro", "valor": "6"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "atributo": "plantStand",
    "similaridade": "Não",
    "valores": [
      {"chave": "Desconhecido", "valor": "?"},
      {"chave": "Normal", "valor": "0"},
      {"chave": "lt-normal", "valor": "1"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "atributo": "precip",
    "similaridade": "Não",
    "valores": [
      {"chave": "Desconhecido", "valor": "?"},
      {"chave": "lt-normal", "valor": "0"},
      {"chave": "Normal", "valor": "1"},
      {"chave": "gt-normal", "valor": "2"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "atributo": "temp",
    "similaridade": "Não",
    "valores": [
      {"chave": "Desconhecido", "valor": "?"},
      {"chave": "lt-norm", "valor": "0"},
      {"chave": "norm", "valor": "1"},
      {"chave": "gt-norm", "valor": "2"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "atributo": "hail",
    "similaridade": "Não",
    "valores": [
      {"chave": "Desconhecido", "valor": "?"},
      {"chave": "Yes", "valor": "0"},
      {"chave": "No", "valor": "1"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "atributo": "cropHist",
    "similaridade": "Sim",
    "valores": [
      {"chave": "Desconhecido", "valor": "?"},
      {"chave": "diff-1st-yr", "valor": "0"},
      {"chave": "same-1st-yr", "valor": "1"},
      {"chave": "same-lst-two-yrs", "valor": "2"},
      {"chave": "same-lst-sev-yrs", "valor": "3"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "atributo": "areaDamaged",
    "similaridade": "Sim",
    "valores": [
      {"chave": "Desconhecido", "valor": "?"},
      {"chave": "scattered", "valor": "0"},
      {"chave": "low-areas", "valor": "1"},
      {"chave": "upper-areas", "valor": "2"},
      {"chave": "whole-field", "valor": "3"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "atributo": "severity",
    "similaridade": "Sim",
    "valores": [
      {"chave": "Desconhecido", "valor": "?"},
      {"chave": "Minor", "valor": "0"},
      {"chave": "pot-severe", "valor": "1"},
      {"chave": "severe", "valor": "2"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "atributo": "seedTmt",
    "similaridade": "Não",
    "valores": [
      {"chave": "Desconhecido", "valor": "?"},
      {"chave": "none", "valor": "0"},
      {"chave": "fungicida", "valor": "1"},
      {"chave": "Outros", "valor": "2"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "atributo": "germination",
    "similaridade": "Sim",
    "valores": [
      {"chave": "Desconhecido", "valor": "?"},
      {"chave": "90-100%", "valor": "0"},
      {"chave": "80-89%", "valor": "1"},
      {"chave": "lt-80%", "valor": "2"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "atributo": "plantGrowth",
    "similaridade": "Não",
    "valores": [
      {"chave": "Desconhecido", "valor": "?"},
      {"chave": "Norm", "valor": "0"},
      {"chave": "Abnorm", "valor": "1"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "atributo": "leaves",
    "similaridade": "Não",
    "valores": [
      {"chave": "Norm", "valor": "0"},
      {"chave": "Abnorm", "valor": "1"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "atributo": "leafspotsHalo",
    "similaridade": "Não",
    "valores": [
      {"chave": "Desconhecido", "valor": "?"},
      {"chave": "absent", "valor": "0"},
      {"chave": "yellow-halos", "valor": "1"},
      {"chave": "no-yellow-halos", "valor": "2"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "atributo": "leafspotsMarg",
    "similaridade": "Não",
    "valores": [
      {"chave": "Desconhecido", "valor": "?"},
      {"chave": "w-s-marg", "valor": "0"},
      {"chave": "no-w-s-marg", "valor": "1"},
      {"chave": "dna", "valor": "2"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "atributo": "leafspotSize",
    "similaridade": "Não",
    "valores": [
      {"chave": "Desconhecido", "valor": "?"},
      {"chave": "lt-1/8", "valor": "0"},
      {"chave": "gt-1/8", "valor": "1"},
      {"chave": "dna", "valor": "2"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "atributo": "leafShread",
    "similaridade": "Não",
    "valores": [
      {"chave": "Desconhecido", "valor": "?"},
      {"chave": "absent", "valor": "0"},
      {"chave": "Present", "valor": "1"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "atributo": "leafMalf",
    "similaridade": "Não",
    "valores": [
      {"chave": "Desconhecido", "valor": "?"},
      {"chave": "Absent", "valor": "0"},
      {"chave": "Present", "valor": "1"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "atributo": "leafMild",
    "similaridade": "Não",
    "valores": [
      {"chave": "Desconhecido", "valor": "?"},
      {"chave": "Absent", "valor": "0"},
      {"chave": "Upper-surf", "valor": "1"},
      {"chave": "Lower-surf", "valor": "2"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "atributo": "stem",
    "similaridade": "Não",
    "valores": [
      {"chave": "Desconhecido", "valor": "?"},
      {"chave": "Norm", "valor": "0"},
      {"chave": "Abnorm", "valor": "1"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "atributo": "lodging",
    "similaridade": "Sim",
    "valores": [
      {"chave": "Desconhecido", "valor": "?"},
      {"chave": "Yes", "valor": "0"},
      {"chave": "No", "valor": "1"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "atributo": "stemCankers",
    "similaridade": "Sim",
    "valores": [
      {"chave": "Desconhecido", "valor": "?"},
      {"chave": "Absent", "valor": "0"},
      {"chave": "below-soil", "valor": "1"},
      {"chave": "Above-soil", "valor": "2"},
      {"chave": "Above-sec-nde", "valor": "3"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "atributo": "cankerLesion",
    "similaridade": "Não",
    "valores": [
      {"chave": "Desconhecido", "valor": "?"},
      {"chave": "dna", "valor": "0"},
      {"chave": "Brown", "valor": "1"},
      {"chave": "dk-brown-blk", "valor": "2"},
      {"chave": "tan", "valor": "3"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "atributo": "fruitingBodies",
    "similaridade": "Não",
    "valores": [
      {"chave": "Desconhecido", "valor": "?"},
      {"chave": "Absent", "valor": "0"},
      {"chave": "Present", "valor": "1"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "atributo": "externalDecay",
    "similaridade": "Não",
    "valores": [
      {"chave": "Desconhecido", "valor": "?"},
      {"chave": "Absent", "valor": "0"},
      {"chave": "firm-and-dry", "valor": "1"},
      {"chave": "watery", "valor": "2"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "atributo": "mycelium",
    "similaridade": "Não",
    "valores": [
      {"chave": "Desconhecido", "valor": "?"},
      {"chave": "Absent", "valor": "0"},
      {"chave": "Present", "valor": "1"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "atributo": "intDiscolor",
    "similaridade": "Não",
    "valores": [
      {"chave": "Desconhecido", "valor": "?"},
      {"chave": "None", "valor": "0"},
      {"chave": "Brown", "valor": "1"},
      {"chave": "Black", "valor": "2"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "atributo": "sclerotia",
    "similaridade": "Não",
    "valores": [
      {"chave": "Desconhecido", "valor": "?"},
      {"chave": "Absent", "valor": "0"},
      {"chave": "Present", "valor": "1"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "atributo": "fruitPods",
    "similaridade": "Não",
    "valores": [
      {"chave": "Desconhecido", "valor": "?"},
      {"chave": "Norm", "valor": "0"},
      {"chave": "Diseased", "valor": "1"},
      {"chave": "few-present", "valor": "2"},
      {"chave": "dna", "valor": "3"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "atributo": "fruitSpots",
    "similaridade": "Não",
    "valores": [
      {"chave": "Desconhecido", "valor": "?"},
      {"chave": "Absent", "valor": "0"},
      {"chave": "Colored", "valor": "1"},
      {"chave": "Brown-w/blk-specks", "valor": "2"},
      {"chave": "Distort", "valor": "3"},
      {"chave": "dna", "valor": "4"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "atributo": "seed",
    "similaridade": "Não",
    "valores": [
      {"chave": "Desconhecido", "valor": "?"},
      {"chave": "Norm", "valor": "0"},
      {"chave": "Abnorm", "valor": "1"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "atributo": "moldGrowth",
    "similaridade": "Não",
    "valores": [
      {"chave": "Desconhecido", "valor": "?"},
      {"chave": "Absent", "valor": "0"},
      {"chave": "Present", "valor": "1"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "atributo": "seedDiscolor",
    "similaridade": "Não",
    "valores": [
      {"chave": "Desconhecido", "valor": "?"},
      {"chave": "Absent", "valor": "0"},
      {"chave": "Present", "valor": "1"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "atributo": "seedSize",
    "similaridade": "Não",
    "valores": [
      {"chave": "Desconhecido", "valor": "?"},
      {"chave": "Norm", "valor": "0"},
      {"chave": "lt-norm", "valor": "1"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "atributo": "shriveling",
    "similaridade": "Não",
    "valores": [
      {"chave": "Desconhecido", "valor": "?"},
      {"chave": "Absent", "valor": "0"},
      {"chave": "Present", "valor": "1"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "atributo": "roots",
    "similaridade": "Não",
    "valores": [
      {"chave": "Desconhecido", "valor": "?"},
      {"chave": "Norm", "valor": "0"},
      {"chave": "Rotted", "valor": "1"},
      {"chave": "galls-cysts", "valor": "2"}
    ]
  }
]
```

A sample case:

```
{
    "caso": 1,
    "doenca": "diaporthe-stem-canker",
    "areaDamaged": "low-areas",
    "cankerLesion": "Brown",
    "cropHist": "same-1st-yr",
    "date": "Outubro",
    "externalDecay": "firm-and-dry",
    "fruitSpots": "dna",
    "fruitingBodies": "Present",
    "fruitPods": "Norm",
    "germination": "90-100%",
    "hail": "Yes",
    "intDiscolor": "None",
    "leafMalf": "Absent",
    "leafMild": "Absent",
    "leafShread": "absent",
    "leafspotsHalo": "absent",
    "leafspotSize": "dna",
    "leafspotsMarg": "dna",
    "leaves": "Abnorm",
    "lodging": "No",
    "moldGrowth": "Absent",
    "mycelium": "Absent",
    "plantGrowth": "Abnorm",
    "plantStand": "Normal",
    "precip": "gt-normal",
    "roots": "Norm",
    "sclerotia": "Absent",
    "seed": "Norm",
    "seedDiscolor": "Absent",
    "seedSize": "Norm",
    "seedTmt": "none",
    "severity": "pot-severe",
    "shriveling": "Absent",
    "stem": "Abnorm",
    "stemCankers": "Above-sec-nde",
    "temp": "norm"
  }
```

So where I have areaDamaged: low-areas, I want to take from areaDamaged the value of low-areas. Anyone knows the better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume that by "better" you mean "more efficient".

If so, then as long as you have arrays everywhere, there is no "better" way.

However, it looks like your arrays hold some reference data, which you'll be accessing over and over again. What I sometimes do in such cases is convert the arrays to maps and they work faster, something like this:

```
var refDataMap = {};

var refDataItem, refDataValue;

for (var i = 0; i < refData.length; i++) {
    refDataItem = refData[i];
    refDataMap[refDataItem.atributo] = refDataItem;
    refDataItem.valoresMap = {};
    for (var j = 0; j < refDataItem.valores.length; j++) {
        refDataValue = refDataItem.valores[j];
        refDataItem.valoresMap[refDataValue.chave] = refDataValue.valor;
    }
}

var result = refDataMap["seed"].valoresMap["Abnorm"]; // Gives value 1
```

I've created some performance tests and can see that accessing a map like this is ~25% faster than iterating over these arrays (http://jsben.ch/#/ADhFC).

However, if you include the map initialization sequence into the test, then array is twice as fast if measured for a single access (http://jsben.ch/#/GQBC0).

I've observed that you need to access this ~50 times for the overhead of the map initialization to start paying off (http://jsben.ch/#/b6vbs).

Comment: Wow, thanks! To be honest I was looking for a easier way to implement but your answer is simply awesome for implementation and efficience. Thanks so much! And yeah, I will access this over than 300 times, so it will be better for me

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the properties "valor" and "chave" inside the json you can use the key/value direct in the json structure.

Like this:

```
var propriedades = {    
    "areaDamaged" : {
        "similaridade": "Sim",
        "valores": {
             "Desconhecido" : "?",
             "scattered" : "0",
             "low-areas" : "1",
             "upper-areas" : "2",
             "whole-field" : "3"
         }
    },
 ...
```

Then you can get the value easier:

```
var valor = propriedades["areaDamaged"].valores["low-areas"];
```

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I needed